# Why Method -> "NeuralNetwork" does not work for me?

Tags: machine-learning

Mastering my Machine Learning, I try arithmetic:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
trainingset = {"2+2" -> 4, "2+3*2" -> 8, "(12+7)*5" -> 95, "7*6" -> 42,
 "7+22" -> 29, "4+5" -> 9, "4*1+5" -> 9, "17*3+4*5" -> 41, "7+9*2" -> 25, "11+3" -> 14, 
"6+6" -> 12, "4*5+6" -> 26, "5*7" -> 35, "3*2" -> 6, "3+2" -> 5, "9*3" -> 27, 
   "3*9" -> 27, "6*3+8*2" -> 34, "5*4" -> 20};
```

Making use of different methods, I'd like to compare the results:

```
p = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "RandomForest"]; p["4+6"]
```

> 24.6316

```
r = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "LinearRegression"]; r["4+6"]
```

> 20.3651

```
t = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]; t["4+6"]
```

> 26.

```
u = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "DecisionTree"]; u["4+6"]
```

> 14.1

```
w = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "GradientBoostedTrees"]; w["4+6"]
```

> 13.7925

However,

```
s = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"]; s["4+6"]
```

> Beep:The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation.

Looking in the help, I don't understand that behavior of `Predict`.

Addition. I mean the result with `Method -> "NeuralNetwork"`. It's clear that a training set of 19 elements is too small to train `Predict`. My another question is how to generate a training set consisting of 200 examples in an automatic way.

Comment: Works fine in version 11.3 on macOS (apart from the fact that result of `"4+6"` is rubbish). Probably a nasty memory related bug. Try also to restart the kernel. Also you can go into the help menu and click "Why the beep?..." Maybe that gives you some idea what happened. Maybe not.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Thank you for your interest to my question. If you carefully read my answer, you will see I looked in "Why Beep". A new kernel does not help.

Comment: Ah sorry. Well, then I guess this is a OS-related bug.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: I work in version 11.3 on Windows 10 32-bit.

Comment: It works fine on my machine running Windows 10, 64bit

Comment: @Niki Estner: Thank you for  good news. Can you kindly tell us the obtained result? TIA.

Comment: You get a different result every time you run it with a fresh kernel. Usually around 25, because that's the mean of the training values. You realize that this isn't going to work, right?

Comment: @Niki Estner: Yes. I hope I am clear in my question. The command quits at the first example of 19.

Comment: @user64494 I think it's time to contact support about it.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: I will think about it, but the deficiency is minor. How about my another question: how to generate a training set to this end in an automatic way?