# How to generate a training set in an automatic way?

Tags: list-manipulation, machine-learning

This question is related to [my previous item][1] where arithmetic with machine learning was considered. The results of the `Predict` command were not good because of a small size 19 of a training set

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
trainingset = {"2+2" -> 4, "2+3*2" -> 8, "(12+7)*5" -> 95, "7*6" -> 42,
 "7+22" -> 29, "4+5" -> 9, "4*1+5" -> 9, "17*3+4*5" -> 41, "7+9*2" -> 25, "11+3" -> 14, 
"6+6" -> 12, "4*5+6" -> 26, "5*7" -> 35, "3*2" -> 6, "3+2" -> 5, "9*3" -> 27, 
   "3*9" -> 27, "6*3+8*2" -> 34, "5*4" -> 20};
```

My question is: how to generate such training set of size 200 with one or two additions and multiplications over integers from 0 to 100 in an automatic way?
[1]: [Why Method -> "NeuralNetwork" does not work for me?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178884/why-method-neuralnetwork-does-not-work-for-me)

PS. See the first example at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksSequenceLearning.html#1013067167

Comment: @Niki Estner: Can you kindly base your claim, giving us references? Does  a chess program know what is "knight"?

Comment: @NikiEstner: See the first example at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksSequenceLearning.html#1013067167 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work.

```
rn["num"] := RandomInteger[{0, 100}]
rn["op"] := RandomChoice[{"+", "*"}]

set = ToString @ Row[rn /@ Riffle[Table["num", {#}], "op"]] & /@ 
   RandomInteger[{2, 4}, 200];

set = # -> ToExpression[#] & /@ set;
```

Output looks like

> {"94+66+34*28" -> 1112, "37*40*57" -> 84360, "34*59+27+97" -> 2130, . . .}

---

In the code above the function `rn` (random) makes a random number or operator as needed.  So for example `rn /@ {"num", "op", "num"}` might give me `{1, "+", 2}`.  From there I can [merge](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121) those into a single string.  So the matter is then just creating a series of "num"/"op" lists of the right form.  As an example:

```
Riffle[Table["num", {4}], "op"]
```

> ```
> {"num", "op", "num", "op", "num", "op", "num"}
> ```

So this [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html)/[`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) expression forms the heart of a [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) that I map over a list of (pseudo)random integers of the right specification.

The final step is to take our complete strings and evaluate them as input, and this is performed by [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html).  `# -> ToExpression[#] &` is another `Function` that gives input mapped to output as a series of Rules.

The same operations written in a step by step way:

```
rn["num"] := RandomInteger[{0, 100}]
rn["op"] := RandomChoice[{"+", "*"}]

RandomInteger[{2, 4}, 10];

Table["num", {#}] & /@ %

Riffle[#, "op"] & /@ %

Map[rn, %, {2}]

ToString /@ Row /@ %

Thread[% -> ToExpression /@ %]
```

There are certainly other ways to approach this problem; this is merely what came to mind first as an expedient solution.

Comment: Many thanks from me to you for your work.  Can you kindly comment your code (In order to use it in teaching the code should be understandable to students.)?

Comment: Also the code p = Predict[set, Method -> "RandomForest"]; p["4+6"] results 600785.

Comment: Changing the parameters 100->20, {2,4}->{1,3}, 200->10000, I obtain 22.5 for t["4+6*3"].

Comment: @user64494 Tomorrow I'll add comments or otherwise make the code more transparent.

Comment: @user64494 Sorry, I forgot to return to this.  Hopefully *tomorrow* I will remember. <:-0

Comment: @user64494 Done. Please take a look.

Comment: Many thanks from me to you for your very good explanation.